# How to capture all records in Incremental Fetching using GenerateTableFetch processor in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using Nifi 1.7.1

For my case, the incremental fetching does not seem to work correctly.

All records gets ingested from the database but do not make it all the way to the destination.

Processor used is GenerateTableFetch then Execute SQL and the other corresponding processors down the data processing flow.

Record id is captured correctly on the GenerateTableFetch property state and its up to date as the record id from the  source (db).

However, it will still miss some records when processing the files making the number of records on the destination out of sync with the source from the db.
I have tried increasing the Back Pressure Object Threshold for all the processor connections but still not successful

Am i missing something, Would scheduling times for fetching help?

Comment: How do you prove this statement "All records gets ingested from the database but do not make it all the way to the destination." ?

If they are all being ingested, at what point are they being "lost"?

Comment: From the first processor 'GenerateTableFetch' the value for  the property 'View State ' is the record id of the last ingested record and matches with the latest record id on the db . Although last updated record id is captured under this processor's state, it will only process some records.

Comment: How many records in total (on average) are being fetched? How many are missing?
If you stop the processors after ExecuteSQL and let it build up in the queue, you are already missing records in this queue? If so, need to need the GTF and ES processor configs.

Comment: On average about 10-20 in a week and missing would be 2-5.Thanks for this suggestion. Will  try that . Could you be specific as to what properties/configs for the GTF and ES to check and change?

Comment: I would do the test first, we need to identify where exactly the records are going missing - if they aren't reaching NiFi, then there's llittle we can do - if they get lost at ExecuteSQL, we'll look at the config - if it's in the queue/later in the flow - we'll have to look at that. Beccause it's pretty low traffic, should be relatively simple to identify where the records are going missing

Comment: The processor after ExecuteSQL was stopped over the weekend. As of yesterday and today, a total of 3 new records were inserted on the db from the application. Record ids are 7301,7302 and 7300. Only one record (7300) is held in queue at the moment , missing is 7301 and 7302. For your further advise

Comment: Ok - so the records arent making it past ESQL.

Stop ESQL and let the GTF run - view the FFs that GTF makes and verify that it has created SQL statements (view the FFs in the queue, look at their attr's and you'll see the SQL statements). Make sure those SQL statements are actually returning the records you expect to see.

If they are, drop a blank UpdateAttribute or funnel in and put the ESQL failure relationship to it to see if they are being routed to failure.

Comment: ExecuteSQL was stopped with GTF running. FFs showed sql statement was created successfully. SQL Statement executed separately on db and returned the expected records.  ESQL failure relationship was put in place and set to have failed records routed to the blank UpdateAttribute . No records failed .All went to success.

Comment: I also wanted to point out that if I clear all records on the destination and re-ingest, it will pick up all records, even the ones that were missed earlier. That was the work around I've been using. After a full re-ingest, the issues starts again with the new records coming in. Greatly appreciate your time and assistance thus far. Waiting for your further advise on this

Comment: Interesting - do you have the capacity to upgrade NiFi? Nifi 1.7.1 is >2 years old, there are many bug fixes & improvements to be gained from getting up to 1.12.

Comment: Thankyou, suggestion for upgrade is noted. Thanks again for your time and assistance